# How to map JSON response from a server to the URL that requested it?

Tags: jquery, html, json, url, response

I am new to JSON. I am working on an area that requires me to find out a relation between the URL that sends a JSON request and gets back a JSON response. I want to uniquely identify within an application, which URL calls its corresponding JSON. Please help me or point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried something out in this..?

Comment: I am actually observing a 3rd party application in which I am not allowed to modify the existing code. So I cannot change their json file. I have to introduce my own filter and then work on the **json response** and be able to some how tell which URL caused that json to be fired.

I am planning to use some script like FireBug which does tell me which URL referred to the particular json. But that is just the starting idea. I do not know how to proceed and am stuck on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply append the `window.location.pathname`:

```
json = {somedata: 'foo', url: window.location.pathname };
```

Use `href` instead of `pathname` if you need the entire URL, rather than just the path.

Note that JSON is a protocol and is not specific to jQuery (or JavaScript for that matter, although it is probably the most common usage).

Comment: Thanks for the reply PinnyM. This is a nice solution but I am actually observing a 3rd party application in which I am not allowed to modify the existing code. So I cannot change their json file. I have to introduce my own filter and then work on the **json response** and be able to somehow tell which URL caused that json to be fired.

Comment: If you can't modify the request, the next place would be to look at the request's HTTP-REFERER header and pass that back.  Not as reliable, but usually 'good enough'.  Unfortunately, if you're not able to modify the request, then I doubt you have access to modifying the server response.  In which case, you're limited to the context that fired off the request.  Once you leave that context, you're out of luck.  Will you have access the coding structure that made the request?